# How to register an EC2 instance with Opswork?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-cli, aws-opsworks

I have gone through documentation. I want to register an EC2 instance with Opswork. I followed the steps and now I am running register command on instance which I want to register.

First this give me this error ,

`:user/ is not authorized to perform: Liam:AddUser on resource:`

As mentioin [here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/id_credentials_delegate-permissions.html)

I added this policy ->

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": {
    "Effect": "Allow",
    "Action": "iam:CreateUser",
    "Resource": "*"
  }
}
```

Now after running register command,it is showing this error->

`:user/ is not authorized to perform: iam:AddUserToGroup on resource:`

Which policy should I assign to user so this is able to register an instance with opswork and working properly with opswork.

Answer (score 0):

add one more permission for the IAM CreateGroup as the process is:

the register command does the following:

Creates the following:

An IAM user that bootstraps the agent with the AWS OpsWorks service to provide secure communication.

The user's permissions allow only the opsworks:RegisterInstance action, and they expire after 15 minutes.

An IAM group for the stack, which contains the registered instances' IAM users.

Comment: now after processing this gives following error  ->
opsworks-init: Agent installation failed.
opsworks-init: Please verify the log files found under /var/log/aws/opsworks and submit findings to AWS Support.

Comment: This error has resolved, But another that i face is that one IAM user is created for each EC2 instance that i want to register, Can it done with only one specific user ? Otherwise this will create 100 IAM users for 100 instance, Is it feasible ?

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue and used following policy. More details are here [The AWSOpsWorksRegisterCLI Policy](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/opsworks/latest/userguide/registered-instances-register-registering-template.html)

```
    {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "opsworks:AssignInstance",
        "opsworks:CreateStack",
        "opsworks:CreateLayer",
        "opsworks:DeregisterInstance",
        "opsworks:DescribeInstances",
        "opsworks:DescribeStackProvisioningParameters",
        "opsworks:DescribeStacks",
        "opsworks:UnassignInstance"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "ec2:DescribeInstances"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iam:AddUserToGroup",
        "iam:CreateAccessKey",
        "iam:CreateGroup",
        "iam:CreateUser",
        "iam:ListInstanceProfiles",
        "iam:PassRole",
        "iam:PutUserPolicy"
      ],
      "Resource": [
        "*"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```